# Java: how to parse an html string for XML tool consume?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

Which library would allow me to evaluate xpath on an html string ?

I have tried using the javax package but this seems to fail:

```
String docroot = "<div><i>items <b>sold</b></i></div>";
XPath xxpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
InputSource docroot = new InputSource(new StringReader(subelements)); 
String result = (String) xxpath.evaluate("//b", docroot, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Comment: Please remember next time to expand "seems to fail" substantionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following instead, there were some errors in your code sample:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String docroot = "<div><i>items <b>sold</b></i></div>";
        XPath xxpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(docroot)); 
        String result = (String) xxpath.evaluate("//b", inputSource, XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a parser that is lenient enough to parse in HTML as XML, and those are rare.  I believe TagSoup - http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers/tagsoup - can do it, but it's been a long time since I had a look at it.

(more here: http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers/tagsoup)

Is there any reason you cannot just provide a XHTML snippet?

Answer (score 2):

You want a Java HTML parsing library that can produce a valid XML Document object. Based on this unscientific [library comparison](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/java-html-parsing-library-comparison/) it appears [HTML Cleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net) would do the trick.

From the HTML Cleaner site:

> Although the main motive was to
>   prepare ordinary HTML for XML
>   processing with XPath, XQuery and
>   XSLT, structured data produced by
>   HtmlCleaner may be consumed and
>   handled in menu other ways.

This [documentation link](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php) provides an example of how to read in an HTML string, execute an XPath query, and work with the results.